# Adding new parameter in lyx

Tags: macros, lyx, memoir, input

In texmaker, I create document_setting.tex for input some document attribution like the author, publisher, some attribution in acknowledgements. And then input document_setting in master document report.tex.

Here is a command for a new variable, in gayaan.sty I write:

```
\newcommand{\var}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Var}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{\uppercase{#2}}}
```

In document_setting.tex :

```
\Var{\titling}{Analisis dan Penghitungan Tingkat Kemiskinan}
\var{\subdir}{Subdirectorate of Constraction Statistics}
\var{\nopublication}{05340.1002}
```

In report.tex :

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{gayaan}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\input{document_setting}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\Large{\titling}}
\subdir 
\nopublication

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[5]
\section{example}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

And the result is success, but I can't do this in Lyx. Does anyone know how to do it in lyx? Create something like document-setting.tex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could open "Document settings" in the LyX main menu and put `\input{document_setting}` into the document preamble, or the corresponding code lines.

Comment: yes, I have tried it, last week I get an error message when tried with the same solution. this is my solution : insert child document in master document. child document as document-setting. and define new variabel in document preamble lyx. when I need to write the value of the parameter in another child document, I just write the parameter. I don't know why it just running well now. Thanks Stefan :-)